# Cisco Auto Smartports on catalyst 2960-s

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst

I have Cisco Catalyst 2960-s, I want to configure user defined macros on it. I searched a lot in Cisco documentation but its not for beginners :(

- How to create a user defined macro that runs when a device is connected on a port?
- How to test the IP address of the connected device on an interface ?
- How to block traffic on an interface without shutting it down?

Any ideas about how to do that??

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the macro to do when a device is connected?

Comment: The macro should compare the IP address of the connected device with 192.168.1.20 if its different it will block the traffic. 


**NB**: **1.** I don't use DHCP server, so addresses are set manually.
**2.** On each port i want to allow only one predefined IP address.

Comment: There is a little bit of a problem here... the 2960S is a only a layer2 switch, it has no knowledge of IP addresses unless you enable something like IP Source Guard.  How are you proposing that the switch would know that a port has an attached host that is 192.168.1.20?

Comment: That's true its only L2 switch. But assuming I want to compare the mac address of the connected device and not its IP, can you give me a '**Hello word**' macro?